# settext to a dynamic added textview in another activity

Tags: android

I created two activites, the first one is containing the dynamic added textview and the second one will do some operation then settext to the dynamic added textview in activity one. please help to suggest a sample code for my reference. Thank you!

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult` for that.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Further, if I would like to change my scenario to dynamically change the dynamic added textview in Activity one form another service in a same package, may I know your suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Means want to pass data from activity to activity?

Comment: I would like to pass a text content form a service to a dynamically added textview in my MainActivity.

Comment: can I use the settext in service to update the dynamic textview in my MainActivity? Thanks!

Comment: Oh.. for that you can use Bus Event. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Thank you Piyush, I will go through the content you suggested.

Comment: It will be very efficient and easier for you.!!

Answer (score 0):

To add textViews can dynamically using the following method.

```
private void addChild(boolean right) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        int id = R.layout.unLayout_;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(id, null, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        layout.addView(relativeLayout);
```

}

Comment: Thank you Aldakur! if I would like to settext to textView from my service, do you have any suggestion for that? Thanks!

Comment: You need to pass data inserted in TextView to the second activity. For that you need to insert the data into an array. Create an array in the method onCreate and fill it in method addChild. yourArrayList.add ("yourtext")

Comment: Thank you Aldakur! I will study with your suggested direction.

Comment: OK. To pass the array one activity to another.
First Activity:
`Intent i = new Intent(this, secondActivityName.class);
i.putExtra("key", yourArrrayList);
startActivity(i);`

and in second activity. In onCreate method:
`Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
arrayList  = (ArrayList<String>) bundle.getSerializable("key");`