# Android cannot dynamically add new layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to **dynamically add the following structure of elements into a layout**.

I get a list of items and for each of them I have to insert some elements into a main linear layout (linearLayout2).

I tried some code below, **but it doesn't show the layout**. 
If I add the TextView directly into the parent layout, it is visibile, but if I want to follow the xml structure below, nothing will be added on the screen.

The layout I want to add:

```
    <RelativeLayout>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" />
                <CheckBox />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

AsyncTask OnResponse():

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);

for(int i = 0; i < homeworkList.size(); i++){
                    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(currentActivity,null, R.style.HomeworkLayout);
                    TextView text = new TextView(currentContext);
                    text.setTextAppearance(currentContext,R.style.HomeworkTile);
                    layout.addView(text);
                    linearLayout.addView(layout);
    }
```

Is this a good way of dynamically added things into page?

Why adding the relative layout is not working?

Comment: add `LayoutParams` to your `TextView`

Comment: Check this [enter link description here][1]

Perhaps here is the solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273749/settext-to-a-dynamic-added-textview-in-another-activity/29274167#29274167

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build that kind of layout, u need to use this code (you need to add the relative layout to the linear layout, and then you can put the textviews inside the relative layout)

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);

//Add RelativeLayout to LinearLayout
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(currentActivity,null, R.style.HomeworkLayout);
linearLayout.addView(layout);

for(int i = 0; i < homeworkList.size(); 
{
    //Add TextViews to RelativeLayout
    TextView text = new TextView(currentContext);
    text.setTextAppearance(currentContext,R.style.HomeworkTile);

    //Make sure the TextView got a width and a height
    TableRow.LayoutParams paramsExample = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);
    text.setLayoutParams(paramsExample);


    layout.addView(layout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use layout inflaters for dynamic view loading from java

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_xml_layout,linearLayout,false)
linearLayout.addView(view);
```

And if you want to access subviews

```
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_Id);
```

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-dynamic-layout-using-xml-add.html

Comment: I tried this, works fine and resolves many issues.
But how can I edit some variabiles inside that template. For example, I want to generate 4-5 items with that same template. How should I change the text inside those elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
linearLayout.addView(text);
linearLayout.addView(layout);
```

You are adding both the `TextView` and the `RelativeLayout` to the `LinearLayout`.

You need to add the `TextView` to the `RelativeLayout`, and not create a new `RelativeLayout` for each loop:

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(currentActivity,null, R.style.HomeworkLayout);
    for(int i = 0; i < homeworkList.size(); i++){                
        TextView text = new TextView(currentContext);
        text.setTextAppearance(currentContext,R.style.HomeworkTile);
        layout.addView(text);                 
    }
    linearLayout.addView(layout);
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, but I've tried that, still the same issue.
I copied the code from a version that works (adding the textview to the main layout). When I do it your way I still cannot see anything.

Comment: What happens if you simplify the code a little bit, and add plain TextView's to the LinearLayout instead. Try playing around with the color of the TextView etc just in case they are appearing, but camouflaged in the background.